# Compare Two Json object's value, Find the Difference of objects's value and ouptut to new Json

Tags: javascript

We have two JSON data which we would like to compare and get the difference between the values of two Keys , Count in First JSON data compared with AVG_X in JSON data .

First JSON-

```
var myObject=[
  {
    "Customer": "A",
    "Count": 47
  },
  {
    "Customer": "B",
    "Count": 5
  },
  {
    "Customer": "C",
    "Count": 1
  }
]
```

Second JSON-

```
var myobject1=[
  {
    "Customer": "A",
    "AVG_X": 20
  },
  {
    "Customer": "B",
    "AVG_X": 4
  },
  {
    "Customer": "C",
    "AVG_X": 0
  },
  {
    "Customer": "D",
    "AVG_X": 3
  }
]
```

Now to compare the values the of Count vs AVG_X and get the difference between these two for each Customer and save it in new JSON .

Expected Output Should be something like below -

```
{
"Customer": "A", 
"Diff": 27
},
{
"Customer": "B", 
"Diff": 1 
},
"Customer": "C", 
"Diff": 1 
}
```

Comment: Expected result should be wrapped in an array...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please be aware that neither of the JS arrays are JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the `myObject` and get the difference and store the result in a new object with properties `Customer` and `Diff`.

**If the object with same `Customer` in both array**

```js
var myObject = [
  { Customer: "A", Count: 47 },
  { Customer: "B", Count: 5 },
  { Customer: "C", Count: 1 },
];

var myobject1 = [
  { Customer: "A", AVG_X: 20 },
  { Customer: "B", AVG_X: 4 },
  { Customer: "C", AVG_X: 0 },
  { Customer: "D", AVG_X: 3 },
];

const result = myObject.map((o, i) => ({
  Customer: o.Customer,
  Diff: o.Count - myobject1[i].AVG_X,
}));

console.log(result);
```

**If the object can be present in any position in `myobject1`**

```js
var myObject = [
  { Customer: "A", Count: 47 },
  { Customer: "B", Count: 5 },
  { Customer: "C", Count: 1 },
];

var myobject1 = [
  { Customer: "A", AVG_X: 20 },
  { Customer: "B", AVG_X: 4 },
  { Customer: "C", AVG_X: 0 },
  { Customer: "D", AVG_X: 3 },
];

const result = myObject.map((obj) => {
  const { Customer, Count } = obj;
  const isExist = myobject1.find((o) => o.Customer === Customer);
  if (isExist) return { Customer, Diff: Count - isExist.AVG_X };
  else return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myObject=[
  {
    "Customer": "A",
    "Count": 47
  },
  {
    "Customer": "B",
    "Count": 5
  },
  {
    "Customer": "C",
    "Count": 1
  }
];

var myobject1=[
  {
    "Customer": "A",
    "AVG_X": 20
  },
  {
    "Customer": "B",
    "AVG_X": 4
  },
  {
    "Customer": "C",
    "AVG_X": 0
  },
  {
    "Customer": "D",
    "AVG_X": 3
  }
];

let myobject1_customer_array = myobject1.map(a => a.Customer);

let result = [];
let myobject1_id;

for(var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {

  myobject1_id = myobject1_customer_array.indexOf(myObject[i].Customer);

  if (myobject1_id != -1) {
    
    result.push({
      "Customer": myObject[i].Customer,
      "Diff": Math.abs(myObject[i].Count - myobject1[myobject1_id].AVG_X)
    })
  }
}

console.log(result);
```